# sklearn.linear_model.Lasso does not return trivial solution

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I think following Lasso problem has the trivial solution `[1,2,0,0]` because `np.dot(x, [1,2,0,0])` returns `[[5,7,6,8]]`.

```
clf = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.2)
x = np.matrix([[1,3,4,2],[2,2,1,3],[2,1,1,1],[3,1,2,2]]).transpose()
y = [5,7,6,8]
clf.fit(x, y)
print clf.coef_
print clf.intercept_
```

However, I couldn't obtain [1,2,0,0]. The above Lasso code prints [0, 0,6, -0.400, -0.399] and 6.600.

Why the above code doesn't return [1,2,0,0]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default LASSO model in `scikit-learn` automatically adds an intercept which is not under control of L1 penalty (Intuitively: you don't have to pay for a large intercept, whereas large coefficients are expensive due to the penalty).

Therefore the model will try to get as much explanation from the intercept as possible.

If you want to be fair, let the model know that there's no intercept, and use a very low alpha:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np

clf = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.0001, fit_intercept=False)
x = np.array([[1,3,4,2],[2,2,1,3],[2,1,1,1],[3,1,2,2]], dtype=float).T
y = np.array([5,7,6,8], dtype=float)
clf.fit(x, y)
print(clf.coef_)
```

Then the result will be close to the optimal, not penalized solution:

```
[  1.00000732e+00   1.99959807e+00   2.37193884e-03  -1.07734723e-03]
```

Comment: Useful question and answer. However, I still have similar problems, i.e. cannot find trivial solutions even after disabling the intercept. Are there any other options that affect the fit? FYI, the data is not centered.

Comment: Also, I am using `positive=True` option to get positive coefficients. Does the sklearn implementation of LASSO enforce positivity if alpha is very low? (I am guessing alpha is common penalty weight for sparsity as well as positivity, in which case the answer to my question would be NO)